# Undefined offset:0 error

Tags: php

Everything is working fine but the page is displaying an error:-

> undefined offset:0.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($darr12);$i++){   

    $pro12=$this->Process->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Process.id','Process.subgroup','Process.frequency','Process.USL','Process.LSL','Process.UCL','Process.LCL','Process.range'),'conditions'=>array('Process.part_no'=>$darr12[$i]['samples']['part_no'],'Process.name'=>$darr12[$i]['samples']['process'],'Process.characteristic'=>$darr12[$i]['samples']['characteristic'])));
    $us12=$pro12[0]['Process']['USL'];//error
    $ls12=$pro12[0]['Process']['LSL'];//error
    $rg12=$pro12[0]['Process']['range'];//error
}
```

Comment: Because 0th index is not available in your array.

Comment: u must need to check `print_r($pro12)` first

Comment: `echo "<pre/>";print_r($pro12);` check it and you will itself come to know why error is showing.

Comment: Note that having the `count()` function inside the `for` exit conditions is a bad habit as it's executed each times and can harm performance on big arrays.

Comment: print_r($pro12) is displaying a very big array

Answer (score 0):

Before assign result to variable use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), it will check if you have some results.

```
if(isset($pro12[0])) {
  // code
}
```

This should resolve your problem.